# Strange redirect / rename behavior on website

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have a website that has started exhibiting strange redirect behavior. It is a wordpress site running on Apache.

I've disabled all the wordpress plugins, disabled/baselined the .htaccess file to a wordpress default. None has had any effect.

What is happening  is if you go to:

http://siteurl.com/dir it redirects you to https://siteurl.comdir

(deletes the / between .com and dir)

I've tried googling etc. can't seem to find any clues of where to look. I'd appreciate any tips on where to check/adjust. I've looked at the site's DNS configuration on the hosting provider and I can't see anything that would be affecting it. I have other sites on the same hosting provider/vps and they work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try one thing disable all pugins as well as the activate the default wordpress theme. After then change the permalink to default. I hope this will work for you. Let me know so i can find other solution.

Comment: I disabled the plugins via the database. It isn't loading the site at all. I can't get into the admin panel. If I go to IE it loads the main page (not sure if from cache or not) but as soon as I click the login page it deletes the / and won't load the page. Also, It does this behavior for non-wordpress directories.